# Get a promise with angular2 in dart from an http request?

Tags: dart, angular, dart-async

It seems in the 2.0.0-beta.12 build they removed angular2.http from dart in favor of using dart's built in http classes.

However if you were to do something like the following then property is null until the request sets the property.

```
class Component {
  var property;

  Component() {
    HttpRequest.getString("/path/to/something")
      .then((resp) {
        property = JSON.decode(resp);
      });
  }
}
```

What we really want is a promise place holder for the property until the promise is resolved and the view is updated. So how do you do it in angular2 with dart?

Or is there a different dart/angular2 idiomatic way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpRequest.getString(...)` returns a `Future` (`Promise` in JS/TS land) otherwise you wouldn't be able to call `.then(...)` on the result.

You can either use `async` / `await`

```
class Component {
  var property;

  Component() async {
    await HttpRequest.getString("/path/to/something")
      .then((resp) {
        property = JSON.decode(resp);
      });
    doSomethingAfterRequestReturned();
  }
}
```

nope - you can't use `async` / `await` in a constructor.

Alternatives are static methods or an extra call after object creation. Doing extensive work in the constructor is bad practice anyway.

```
class Component {
  Future<Component> createNewInstance() async {
    var c = new Component();

    await HttpRequest.getString("/path/to/something")
    .then((resp) {
      c.property = JSON.decode(resp);
    });
    return c;
  }

  var property;
}
```

and use it like

```
Component.createNewInstance().then((c) => print(c.property));
```

with an extra call

```
class Component {
  getData() {
    return HttpRequest.getString("/path/to/something")
    .then((resp) {
      property = JSON.decode(resp);
    });
  }

  var property;
}
```

and use it like

```
var c = new Component()
c.getData().then((_) => print(c.property));
```